# Deciphering Work Profession from marriage certificate

Tags: marriage-records, 1910s, profession, hampshire

I received a marriage certificate in the post yesterday from 1918, in the Christchurch district of Hampshire.

I am struggling to read what the groom's work profession was:

[image]

Any thoughts / reasonings are welcome.

---

Ah, I understand he was from overseas and I think the middle line says **New Zealand**. And possibly the first word is **Supplier**?

---

Actually, I now see that his **fathers profession** was also a **Retail Trader**.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I read it as ”Sapper. [New Zealand Tunnelling co.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_Tunnelling_Company)” (Co = company).  So he was a soldier in an engineers regiment. Digging trenches and tunnels presumably.

Comment: Thank you, this will open up a whole new chapter to research. The reason I am interested in him is because he was married to my father's Grand Aunt. And it looks like they ended up in Australia and that she died there in 1984. From the hints I found on Ancestry it seems that her father George may have also died there. Not so sure. So, I thought if I start adding family information in that something will show up,